# Ruby gems disappear on Mac OS Jenkins slave

Tags: ruby, macos, osx-yosemite

I have a few Mac Minis and old Mac Pros we use as Jenkins slaves for automated testing.

Occasionally gems simply disappear and I have to re-install them.  This is using the built-in Ruby from Mac OS Yosemite.
Why does this happen?

I use RVM on my personal Macbook Pro, and occasionally it autonomously decides to switch to a new Ruby version, so it makes sense that it won't have all my gems. When I switch back, the gems are gone again.

As for the slaves, they don't have RVM installed, and the outcome is the same.
Could this be caused by Mac OS updates?

The gems are not installed in a Jenkins workspace, I installed them before we installed the Jenkins agent.
The Macs are shared with the test-automation team who also ssh/sudo on them, but don't do anything in Ruby because their code is Java.

Comment: Have you considered using RVM for this? Also is Jenkins deleting it's workspace every time you run a job? If it is and the gems are installed there it might be removing them.

Comment: You have not told us nearly enough to be able to give anything beyond wild guesses. Files don't randomly disappear on computers, they don't work that way. Are your boxes physically secure? Do you have other people able to login and do they have sudo or root? What do your log files tell you?

Comment: @theTinMan 
The gems are not installed in a Jenkins workspace, I installed them before we installed the jenkins agent. The macs are shared with the test automation team who also ssh/sudo on them, but don't do anything Ruby (their code is java)
As for the slaves, they don't have RVM installed, and the outcome is the same. Could this be caused by mac OS updates ?

Answer (score 0):

> Could this be caused by mac OS updates ?

It could be caused by OS updates, and this is one of the big reasons you should *not* use the system Ruby for your development unless you're content with leaving it plain vanilla. Rightly so, Apple considers that Ruby theirs, and they can and will stomp on it with an update if it suits their purposes and you upgrade the OS.

Instead, at a minimum, install a separate Ruby from source or via Homebrew and consider that yours. Or, investigate using rbenv or RVM on the Jenkins boxes to manage your Rubies, which is what we do. That allows builds to use different Rubies and/or sets of gems and lets you fine-tune the Ruby environment on the Jenkins box to whatever the final-destination Ruby will be.

You say your personal RVM changes on its own? Unh-uh, can't happen on its own; *SOMETHING* told it to change. Don't attribute that stuff to voodoo or juju, something is making those things happen such as your environment variables changed or the .rvmrc file got stomped on. If your RVM configuration is correct it should be very stable; My rbenv and RVM setups have always been very solid unless I screwed them up.

Without dumps of your `gem env` or `rvm info` there's not a whole lot we can do to help you straighten it out. In general though, it sounds like you need to treat your Jenkins hosts like they are production boxes, change them very little, and separate your assets from the vendor's.